# Points inside a n-dimensional ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

Let's consider the set of vectors $\textbf{x}$ such that:

$(\textbf{z}^T\textbf{x})^2\le \textbf{z}^TD\textbf{z}$

Here $D$ can be considered to be diagonal, and in any case is a matrix related to $\textbf{x}$. Also we can
consider the set of all vectors $\textbf{z}$ normalized. I have to show that this set of vectors are points inside an n-dimensional ellipsoid.

Here my thoughts:

$(\textbf{z}^T\textbf{x})(\textbf{z}^T\textbf{x})\le \textbf{z}^TD\textbf{z}$

$\textbf{z}^T\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T\textbf{z}\le \textbf{z}^TD\textbf{z}$

$\textbf{z}^T(\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T-D)\textbf{z}\le 0$

Since $\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T$ is a positive definite matrix, for the inequality 
$\textbf{z}^T\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T\textbf{z}\le \textbf{z}^TD\textbf{z}$  the matrix $(\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T-D)$ should be positive definite.

It follows that the matrix $(\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T-D)$ should represent an ellipsoid and the set of points represented by $\textbf{z}$ should be inside the ellipsoid since the inequality is represented by $\le$.

Is it correct? I don't know if my considerations about the positive definiteness of the matrices are correct

Comment: Your set of vectors ${\bf x}$ is not clearly defined. Do we have to consider ${\bf z}\ne{\bf 0}$ as given, or do you mean the set of ${\bf x}$ that satisfy your inequality for all ${\bf z}\ne{\bf 0}$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter the second option

Comment: I think that $D$ has to be negative definite for the positive definiteness of $(\textbf{x}\textbf{x}^T-D)$